# How to identify factors in dataset

Tags: r, database

I'm using the adult data set retrieved from UCI (which I call adultdata). I am trying identify factors in my dataset. To start, I am trying to drop observations with missing data, so any row that has a "?" in one of the V1,V2,...,V15 columns, I want to remove. I have tried the following:

```
adultdata1<- adultdata[adultdata$V2 !="?",]
```

and

```
adultdata1<- subset(adultdata, V2!="?")
```

However, the subset adultdata1 has the same number of observation as my original dataset. For some reason, I can't identify any of the factors. I have clarified that they are factors by using:

```
sapply(adultdata, class)
```

A solution that I have come up with, is to identify what numerical value is attributed to "?" by using:

```
as.numeric(adultdata$V2)
```

(It turns out "?" is = 1) then drop the "?" values using:

```
adultdata1<- adultdata[as.numeric(adultdata$V2) !="1",]
```

I have to do this for each variable, V2, V3,...,V15 that contains missing values. I feel like there has to be an easier way? I also would like to be able to identify the values for what they are called, not their numerical category.

Comment: I think that your question is not clear. You are asking to indetify `factor` but the questions is more like "I want to delete strings where V2 is equal to a ?".

Comment: Well, I'm going to need to identify them for future analysis. I would rather be able to use the names given, not their numerical underpinning (ex. 1 is = ?). So I want to call upon them just in general. If I know how to do this, I can also address the problem presented.

Comment: Try looking for any non print character bundled with "?", It has happened to me. You can either susbset by using grep (instead of equality testing) or have a look at the great `stringi` package, particularly `stringi::stri_escape_unicode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strip.white=T is the solution. The factors had a space in front of all the text. In terms of what was written above,

```
adultdata1<- adultdata[adultdata$V2 !=" ?",]
```

and

```
adultdata1<- subset(adultdata, V2!="?")
```

would both work. Notice the space in front of the "?".

Answer (score 0):

Try reading your data in and setting stringsAsFactors=F:

```
read.csv(file = 'myfile',header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

R will default to a factor more often than I'd prefer.  I tend to avoid the factor unless I explicitly want it.

Comment: That shouldn't necessarily matter because `factor("?") == "?"` is TRUE i.e. one can use `!=` and `==` on factors.

Comment: @RichardScriven  You're right.  Any idea why the subset doesn't work?  Maybe "?" is really " ?" or some other subtle difference...